# facebook login not working

Tags: php, javascript, facebook-graph-api

I had implemented facebook login in my project using javascript code. It was working fine, but now it is not working.The login popup was also not working.

code is here

`<fb:login-button autologoutlink="true" perms="email,user_birthday,status_update,publish_stream"></fb:login-button>`

i changed  perms to scope.the popup came but the script problem is still there.

script code used:

```
    <div id="fb-root"></div>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
            FB.init({appId: 'APPID', status: true, cookie: true, xfbml: true});

            /* All the events registered */
            FB.Event.subscribe('auth.login', function(response) {
                // do something with response
                login();
            });
            FB.Event.subscribe('auth.logout', function(response) {
                // do something with response
                logout();
            });

            FB.getLoginStatus(function(response) {
                if (response.session) {
                    // logged in and connected user, someone you know
                    login();
                }
            });
        };
        (function() {
            var e = document.createElement('script');
            e.type = 'text/javascript';
            e.src = document.location.protocol +
                '//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js';
            e.async = true;
            document.getElementById('fb-root').appendChild(e);
        }());

        function login(){
            FB.api('/me', function(response) {
               fqlQuery();//fqlquery function

            });
        }
        function logout(){
            document.getElementById('login').style.display = "none";
        }



        function fqlQuery(){
            FB.api('/me', function(response) {
                 var query = FB.Data.query('select name, hometown_location, sex, pic_square from user where uid={0}', response.id);
                 query.wait(function(rows) {

                   document.getElementById('name').innerHTML =
                     'Your name: ' + rows[0].name + "<br />" +
                     '<img src="' + rows[0].pic_square + '" alt="" />' + "<br />";
                 });
            });
        }
```

is there any other way to correct the problem?? please help....

Comment: PLease be clearer about the "not working"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you're missing the APP ID from the querystring when loading the facebook javascript SDK.  Per https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/login/ they want it there for some reason

```
<div id="fb-root"></div>
<script>(function(d, s, id) {
  var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
  if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
  js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
  js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js#xfbml=1&appId=APP_ID";
  fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
}(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));</script>
```

Also I noted that your login button HTML doesn't have correct attributes.  Per the documentation, `show-faces`, `width`, `max-rows`, and `scope` are the only valid parameters.